# Show that $f(x, y) := e^{xy} \sin(x + y)$ is totally differentiable

Tags: partial-derivative

> Given,
>
> $$f(x, y) := e^{xy} \sin(x + y),$$
>
> I want to show that $f(x, y)$ is totally differentiable.

**Approach**

Since we were never given any example for solving a problem like this, I feel pretty much lost. I'd guess that I have to evaluate the gradient of $f$ at some point, so that's what I already did:

$$\nabla f = {ye^{xy} \sin(x + y) + e^{xy}\cos(x + y) \choose xe^{xy} \sin(x + y) + e^{xy} \cos(x + y)}$$

Unfortunately, I don't see where to go from here.

**Edit after discussion in the comments**

I have to show that the partial derivatives are continiuous - which they are since they are compositions of continiuous functions. Therefore, $f$ is totally differentiable.

Comment: You've basically done it... do those partial derivatives exist everywhere?

Comment: Just check that the partial derivatives are **continuous**; this is a well-known sufficient condition for differentiability.

Comment: Is this definitely the same procedure for totally differentiability?

Comment: Ah, I found the necessary theorem. I have to show that the partial derivatives are continiuous - as you said. :-) I'll try to figure that out.

Comment: Okay, well, I guess it's kind of obvious that the partial derivatives are continiuous since they are a composition of continiuous functions, aren't they?

Comment: @Noobian: yes indeed

Comment: Forget about the "totally" here. The question is whether this function is "differentiable".

Comment: Why? It was mentioned in the excercise. Or are "totally differentiable" and "differentiable" the same properties?